# Is it allowed to use a period before thereby?

Tags: sentence-construction, punctuation, formal-language

I did use a period before **thereby** but I am not sure whether it should be replaced by other punctuation form in this paragraph?

> This skill, along with academic preparation in the USA can make his work more credible to the local authorities and the general public. **Thereby,** receiving the support necessary to promote cooperation and research in the sustainable use of natural resources.

Comment: You need a comma after USA. The construction in the second part of your text is not a sentence. If you wished to lead it with **thereby** in a separate sentence, you need to change the participle **receiving** into a verb, as in: **Thereby, it receives the support.....**

Answer (score 1):

In the example paragraph, the sentence starting with "Thereby" reads as a continuation of the previous sentence. This feels awkward, although it would be understood. It can be merged into the previous sentence.

If one wants to start this sentence with "thereby", one should as the comment by Ronald Sole suggests, follow it with a verb rather than  a participle:

> Thereby, it receives the support necessary to promote cooperation and research in the sustainable use of natural resources.

However, the word "thereby" is particularly associated with legal writing, often legal writing overusing legal jargon, and with bureaucratic writing. It can often be replaced with "so" or "by this means" or some similar wording, and the quality of the writing will be improved thereby. As always, context and style matters, and the word can be used in good writing.

I would also say it is not a matter of "using a period before 'thereby'" but of "starting a sentence with 'thereby'". The period is merely an indication that the previous sentence has ended (and not the only possible indication either). The issue would be the same if it was the first sentence in a paragraph or in a text, although in such a case it is hard to see what would supply the context needed by the use of "thereby". The word "thereby" is not often used at the start of something, because it refers back to something that has come before.

Answer (score 0):

here 'thereby' is in continuation of the statement, so;

....and the general public, thereby, receiving the ....

Comment: You're right about the comma usage after the word _public_. However, I don't think a comma belongs after the word _thereby_.